# "I hadn't known about it" (tense choice)

Tags: past-perfect

Let's consider the following conversation:

- Why don't you use such a nice application as [some application]? It can do this, it can also do that.
- **I hadn't known about it**.

Is it correct to use the past perfect here? If not, what is the right tense to use?

Comment: "I didn't know it before"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this construction makes sense and is idiomatic. The past perfect shows that the person did not know about it up to this point, but now they do (because the person told them). It says, "at each of the points where I made the decision in the past, I did not know about the alternative."

The past perfect is particularly appropriate because the question has the form "Why *don't* you use...". If the question had asked "Why *didn't* you use..." then a more appropriate response would be "I didn't know...".

Comment: I maybe wrong but the question "Why didn't you use..." sounds to me like some particular past event is being considered. Then it is OK to answer "I didn't know...". But what if question asks about a time period before something - "Why hadn't you read this book before I gave it to you?" - then the answer again should use the past perfect - "I hadn't known about this book". Is everything right?

Comment: @Alexey "Why didn't you use..." could be referring to a particular event or to a series of events in the past. Yes, if the question specifies "Why hadn't you read..." then "I hadn't known..." would be good. However, if the question is "Why haven't you read", I think "I didn't know" would be more natural than "I haven't known".

Answer (score 1):

It isn't idiomatic.

You would just say "I didn't know about that".  In this context, the verb "know" describes a state, so we tend to use "I know" instead of "I am knowing", and we say "I knew" instead of "I have known" or "I had known".

If there is an action verb then past perfect might be appropriate, but is probably not needed, without further context.

> I know that app, and I *had* installed it. But I removed it last week because I'd heard it spies on your emails.

Comment: But doesn't the answer "I didn't know about that" assume some particular point in the past time, some particular time in the past? My answer instead uses the past perfect to indicate the period of time before the person told me about the application.